# Terraform/RDS: Create DB users after creation inside VPC

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds

Using terraform and AWS I've created a Postgres RDS DB within a VPC. During creation, the superuser is created, but it seems like a bad idea to use this user inside my app to run queries.

I'd like to create an additional access-limited DB user during the terraform apply phase after the DB has been created. The only [solutions](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs) I've found expect the DB to be accessible outside the VPC. For security, it also seems like a bad idea to make the DB accessible outside the VPC.

The first thing that comes to mind is to have terraform launch an EC2 instance that creates the user as part of the userdata script and then promptly terminates. This seems like a pretty heavy solution and terraform would create the instance each time `terraform apply` is run unless the instance is not terminated at the end of the script.

Another option is to pass the superuser and limited user credentials to the server that runs migrations and have that server create the user as necessary. This, however, would mean that the server would have access to the superuser and could do some nefarious things if someone got access to it.

Are there other common patterns for solving this? Do people just use the superuser for everything or open the DB to the outside world?

Comment: What I have usually seen is a setup with a bastion host which is then used to talk to the RDS instance and RDS should almost always be in the private subnet of a VPC.

Comment: I have one of that setup too. Are you suggesting using userdata in the bastion host to provision the DB users? Or a separate script that is run after terraform?

Comment: I'd probably just add users later I guess, on a per-needed basis, i.e., a separate script. But if you already know the users that need access, you could check out the `null_resource` if there isn't another way of doing it in terraform.